# Any special tactics for SEO OFF page in independent and movie video songs website?

Tags: seo

For Independent music video songs website how do the SEO OFF page.
For content site we can submit in article submission, directory submission, social bookmarking etc. can i follow same process in my music site. I have some target keywords (tamil songs, independent tamil songs) to this keywords how to do in search results.

Comment: Sorry but the question is broad and we already have a vast amount of questions and answers regarding off-page SEO. Additonally article submission, directory submission, social bookmarking etc = one way ticket to [Penguin Land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Penguin), I highly recommend that you look up guides written in the last couple of years.

Comment: @Simon Hayter Some told for **music site** don't  do article submission, directory submission, social bookmarking. Do only press release, new paper release and social networks. I don't have any content from my site only music videos so only asked this question